# Como selecionar uma String em formato de coluna? SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, string

Tenho um campo `STATUS` em uma tabela com os seguintes dados:

```
VENDA,COMPRA,DEV.VENDA
```

Preciso fazer uma consulta nesse campo que o resultado seja uma coluna, onde cada linha será uma das strings entre as ','(VÍRGULAS).

Por exemplo:

```
VENDA

COMPRA

DEV.VENDA
```

Comment: Na coluna STATUS o dado é concatenado com virgulas, ou seja, em uma coluna vem os dados VENDA,COMPRA,DEV.VENDA?

Comment: É assim mesmo que a coluna está.

Answer (score 2):

Adaptei uma função que encontrei pessoal, obrigado pela ajuda.

```
create FUNCTION Split(@String varchar(MAX), @Delimiter char(1))       
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(MAX))       
as       
begin      
    declare @idx int       
    declare @slice varchar(8000)       

    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

    while @idx!= 0       
    begin       
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
        if @idx!=0       
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
        else       
            set @slice = @String       

        if(len(@slice)>0)  
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)       

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
        if len(@String) = 0 break       
    end   
return 
end
```

Query:

```
Select * from Split('A-B-C-D-E-F','-')
```

Output:

```
Items
-----
A
B
C
D
E
F
```